# No bags on my airline ticket?

Tags: airlines

I bought a ticket online, and when I received it I found at the passenger part "no bags". Does this means it's not allowed for me to carry any bags with on the flight?

Comment: Which airline? Is it a low-cost carrier? You probably need to pay extra for check-in luggage. But without knowing which airline, hard to say...

Comment: airarabia airline

Answer (score 7):

If you booked through airarabia.com it looks like you have an option to pay extra for luggage. If you didn't select this option, then indeed you will have to pay extra for check-in luggage. Enquire with the airline to see if you can add a luggage fee -- it is usually more expensive at the airport.